# Why am I getting this error? The config used to connect Camel and ActiveMQ Classic are correct

Tags: activemq-classic

```
Cannot find class [org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory] for bean with name 'amqConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/jmsContext.xml];
```

Can any one tell what is happening? The same file is worked for another project.

I added `activemq-broker` and `activemq-all` by seeing the Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The problem doesn't appear to be the file, but rather the problem appears to be the Java classpath (as the error message indicates). You need to put the jar which contains `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` on your classpath. I recommend using the appropriate version of the [`activemq-client` dependency](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-client/versions).